# How do I achieve Wordpress Pagination for images?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination

I am using a plugin called elementskit gallery, I wanted to achieve a pagination for the images. Pls see the attached link here:
https://staging5.cherished-memories.studio/wedding-collections/test-gallery/first-look

I read a lot of post here but those are for post_page. But how about for the gallery? Sorry I am not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You are packing way too many images onto the webpage.

If your goal is to limit the 10 minute loading time that it is causing, here are a few steps you can do...

1. Install a lazyload plugin to set all the images to lazy load upon
   scrolling into view.
2. Trying to find a better image gallery plugin that does some type of infinite loading or ajax load upon scrolling to the end of the gallery.
3. Limit the size of the image you are loading on the grid view and only show the actual sized image when user clicks on the image.

bottom line is, the current plugin might not be the right way you should approach this issue, dumping every image into that gallery can be taken care of in a more organized approach.

Comment: Hi Vico, thank you for your comment, currently I am not looking for making the website loads faster. It just that I want the images inside the plugin I used to make it in pagination, hoping for a custom code. As my guide if this is possible of course.

Comment: coding might be out of the scope for you, I suggest you trying to find a plugin that does the pagination you want out of the box. What you have in the screenshot is a masonry photo gallery, usually they do not paginate.

Comment: https://fooplugins.com/foogallery-wordpress-gallery-plugin/pagination/
Here is one that might have what you need.